# Embed bold face markup in Haddock documentation

Tags: haskell, haddock

Is there a way to get bold faced text when documenting Haskell source code with haddock markup? There is / / for emphasis, but nothing obvious for strong. I'm hoping for 
an elegant hack but I'll settle for a kludgy workaround...

AfC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature was pushed to HEAD yesterday.

The markup is `__This is some bold text__`. You don't need to escape single underscores.

Answer (score 1):

Add '@' to your text and it will be bold:

Bold only one word, bold to the first delimiter like space and etc...

`@text1 text2`

here bold only text1 word.

Or wrap in bold some text:

`@bold text examples in haddock@`

Comment: Hm. Don't think so, unless your version of haddock parses a newer version of the syntax. A single @ results in an error (ie, no documentation generated for that function), and @some_name@ results in <code>...</code> (ie, monospaced), which is what I'd expect from http://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/ch03s08.html §3.8.7

Comment: That's indeed wrong, there is no markup for bold. It's currently being implemented and will hopefully make it into 7.8. The markup will be `__This is some bold text__`